Roslyn : Как получить NamespaceDeclarationSyntax в Roslyn C#?
У меня есть метод который парсит код C#.
На вход этого метода подается код в виде строки. После чего с помощью синтаксического дерева я хочу получить список namespace.
Проблема заключается в том, что если namespace объявлен так namespace MyNamespace;, то _root.Members.OfType<NamespaceDeclarationSyntax>() будет равен null.
Однако, если объявить namespace, как namespace MyNamespace { }, то всё будет номально.
Помогите, пожалуйста, найти решение данной проблемы?
Код всего метода
public FileModel ParseEntitiesFromFile(string code)
{
    var fileModel = new FileModel()
    {
        Name = nameFile
    };
    var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code);
    var _root = syntaxTree.GetCompilationUnitRoot();
    fileModel.CodeEtities.Namespaces.AddRange(GetListNamespacesModel(_root.Members.OfType<NamespaceDeclarationSyntax>()));
    return fileModel;
}

Пример кода, который подается в метод
namespace MyNamespace;

public class MyClass { 

}


BaseNamespaceDeclarationSyntax?

Большое спасибо, помогло! Добавьте как ответ, я помечу, что это решение

Можете написать его самостоятельно, я пасс.

понял........................................

из комментария EvgeniyZ, понял, что нужно использовать BaseNamespaceDeclarationSyntax

Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].
